# What can be done about a vanity top not flush against the base?

Tags: bathroom, vanity

I am installing a new vanity / top combo in a bathroom I am in the process of remodeling.  I leveled and roughed the base and placed the vanity top (provided with the base) on to check the fit and align it with the p-trap.

Everything was fine following the [Instructions](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/08/0801be08-e512-4061-be9a-191c3f8ce926.pdf) until I got to step 5 (installing the top).  While attempting to center the top on the base and get it flush (ish) against the wall, I noticed that the top does not appear to "sit" correctly on the base, a subject about which the instructions are noticeably silent.
The front and back of the vanity top appear fine, but the sides of the top that would normally touch the base appear to extend too far to the sides of the base for the silicone adhesive to be useful.

Should I use shims (or some other technique) to bring the base in contact with the top or is everything here in order and I'm over thinking it?  Could this be a defect?

I purchased the vanity from Home Depot.  I can add additional images or information if needed.

### Details

- URL:  http://www.homedepot.com/p/St-Paul-Madeline-24-in-Vanity-in-Chestnut-with-Composite-Vanity-Top-in-White-MD24P2COM-CN/204718251
- Model#: MD24P2COM-CN
- Top Material: Engineered quartz composite
- Base Material: Particle Board
- Additional Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw1To.jpg

### Pictures

[image: Vanity Top][image: Left Side][image: Right Side]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would not be uncommon to install blocking around on the inside top edge of the vanity cabinet to butt up against the top assembly to hold it level without the top rocking around. Such blocking could be pieces of wood 3/4" thick that you glue or screw to the cabinet sides at the necessary height.

As far as that edge along the sides....only you the installer is apt to be looking up under there to see that. I would think that you can just leave that area open. For sure I would avoid the temptation to smear it full if caulk or sealer.

Another thing. You probably want to get the sink top all installed without general regard to where the drain down spout is located relative to the drain piping. The P-trap and the drain piping is all designed to be adjustable to fit to the sink installation and not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  By leaving the side areas open, I will likely only be able to adhere the front and back of the top to the base.  Will this provide adequate adhesion?  Like you say, the look underneath isn't as important to me as making sure I install it properly.  Your point regarding the P-trap positioning makes sense; I'll make sure to do that.

Comment: It does not really take that much to hold the top in place. (I am not sure you are using adhesive for this or some types of brackets and/or fasteners). But if you are concerned there is nothing stopping you from adding a blocking strip along the top inside edge or each cabinet side.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a shot and post the results.